# Copy and delete files from SFTP folder

Tags: sftp, winscp

I have to pick (remove) the files with file mask `FileName_A_*` and `FileName_B_*` from SFTP location and place them in an sharedrive.

I tried using WinSCP. I have created an `HourlyFile.txt` file with below code and placed it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP` . Another batch file `HourlyFile.bat` to execute the script from `HourlyFile.txt`

HourlyFile.txt:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp..........
get -filemask="FileName_A_*" /outbound/test/* \\sharedrive
get -filemask="FileName_B_*" /outbound/test/* \\sharedrive
del /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
del /outbound/test/FileName_B_* 
exit
```

HourlyFile.bat:

```
winscp.com /script=HourlyFile.txt
pause
```

I tried with below options to delete the file but got the error message *"Unknown command"*. Also the above code is copying subfolder from `/outbound/test/` , which it should not.

Commands tried:

```
del /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
-del /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
delete /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
delete /outbound/test/FileName_A_20190604_090002
delete /outbound/test/FileName_A_20190604_090002.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to download and delete the files, you better use [`-delete` switch of the `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#delete). This way, you can be sure that WinSCP deletes only those files that were really successfully downloaded.

```
get -delete /outbound/test/FileName_A_* \\sharedrive\
get -delete /outbound/test/FileName_B_* \\sharedrive\
```

*See WinSCP article [How do I create script that synchronizes files and deletes synchronized files from source afterward?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_delete_synchronized_files)*

---

To answer your literal question: WinSCP has no `del` command. WinSCP has [`rm` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm):

```
rm /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
rm /outbound/test/FileName_B_*
```

Answer (score -1):

On some Unix servers the wildcard command would be:

```
mrm  /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
```

, in the event

```
rm  /outbound/test/FileName_A_*
```

doesn't work, returning error:

rm: Access failed: File not found (/outbound/test/FileName_A_*)